# how to extract a still image from a city public webcam feed.... can ffmpeg do this?

Tags: image, ffmpeg, extract

Was at a bit of a loss where to ask for help on this one, so figured would try my luck with you fine folk!

Im trying to work out a way to pull a still image from this public webcam feed:
https://www.sutherlandshire.nsw.gov.au/Outdoors/Beaches/Webcam-Wanda

the in-browser player seems to be some java player… any ideas how to reverse engineer that? can ffmpeg take a feed from this somehow?

thanks in advance, grateful for any ideas, hacks or otherwise!
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a tool like [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) to try to get the video link

`yt-dlp "https://www.sutherlandshire.nsw.gov.au/Outdoors/Beaches/Webcam-Wanda" --get-url`

and then use the result with ffmpeg,

`ffmpeg -i "https://cams.cdn-surfline.com/cdn-au/au-cronullawanda/chunklist.m3u8" -vframes 1 image.jpg`

Comment: OMG, thank you, that works! What a handy little utility. Thanks again!